# Error invalid instance URLs: resource "google_compute_instance_group" "t-compute-instance-group"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

**Goal**: Create a compute instance and add it to an unmanaged instance group in GCP using terraform.

**Issue**: A compute instance and an unmanaged instance group are being created successfully, but the instance is not being added to the group and giving:
**Error invalid instance URLs:
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "t-compute-instance-group"**

Able to add the instance to the group manually after running the terraform configuration though.

Service account key has **Project Editor** permission assigned.

Code: https://github.com/sagar-aj7/terraform_unmanaged_inst_group

Comment: Have you tried using self link instead?

Answer (score 10):

I've hit the same problem, what worked for me was to use the `selflink` instead of the `id`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "backend-instances" {
  name         = "..."
  zone         = "${var.availability_zone}"

  instances = ["${google_compute_instance.node.*.self_link}"]

  named_port {
    name = "http"
    port = "8080"
  }

  named_port {
    name = "https"
    port = "8443"
  }

  ..
}
```

I'm on the google provider version `2.8.0`. I guess it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: Can't believe this hasn't been up-voted. It solved my problem. My scenario is a bit different: I use a splat expression for the list of VMs: `instances = google_compute_instance.vm[*].id`. It worked for the *1st* run of `terraform apply`. But when I want to add more VMs to the IG and re-run `terraform apply`, it failed with the above error. Switching to `.self_link` solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, glad that it worked :)

Comment: Wow saved my life.  I'd been passing id and spent about 2 hours trying to figure it out.  Funny part is the plan/apply looked good but always got "Error invalid instance URLs:"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The solution was to update the google terraform provider to a newer version (3.52.0). This fixed the issue and created the instance group with the assigned instance.